# React-Native can't resolve module for fonts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm starting a very basic build.
I'm using `create-react-native-app' and yarn for pm.

From there all I have tried to accomplish is to load in 'native-base' for some UI elements.

From the app.js file the only thing I've added is a Button Component from native-base.

`<Button> <Text></Text> </Button>`

And have included native-base.

After receiving some errors that it `couldn't resolve module '@expo/vector-icons'` I went and installed @expo/vector-icons, and for the hell of it ran `react-native link`.

Now it can find @expo/vector-icons but it can't find the fonts starting with `Ionicons.ttf`.

SO. From there I downloaded all the fonts to a `assets/fonts/` directory and then included this in my **app.js** file based off some documentation I found on the expo site.

```
import { Font } from 'exponent';
///
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'ionicons': require('./assets/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
    });
  }
///
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way I load custom fonts is by adding them in the Info.plist file as a list of Font provided by the application:

[image]

And they also need to be in the provided resources of the Build Phases:

[image]

After that, you can use it in the fontFamily property in CSS in react native. Make sure you also clean and build the project again after adding the fonts so they are copied to the device.

Comment: How do you "clean and build"? I added a font but i keep getting unrecognized font error. :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/43301962/1828637 (I'm not using create-react-native-app just regular react-native init)

Comment: @Noitidart It could be two things. Either the font is not in the device or the font-family of the font you are using is wrong. Keep in mind the font-family is not always the same as the file name. Usually is the first issue so to clean and build you need to either react-native run-ios to generate the build and run it again or the way I do it is I open the project in Xcode directly and run it with the "play" button. If you added these in Xcode and modified the react-native code right away, the issue is that the fonts were not copied over.

Comment: Thanks very much for that insight @sfratini - when I open xcode I do see the font in the resources and in the copy build phase. How can I see the font-family name (if it is not the filename)?

Comment: @Noitidart you can use something like that in the AppDelegate https://coderwall.com/p/gdpyjq/how-to-list-all-available-fonts-in-xcode-by-family-name and then check the logs when the app starts. That snippet will list all the fonts iOS is detecting.

Comment: Thank you @sfratini I will test now! :)

Comment: Thank you @sfratini soooooo much!!! You were right!!! the ios-glyphs.ttf was not `ios-glyphs` it was `Icon8` who would have though!! Thank you sir very much!