# Vector font not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I already had run `react-native start` and then `react-native run-ios`. So my app is running.

I placed ios-glyphs.ttf into a folder called fonts in my root directory. So `./fonts`. I then added to package.json this:

```
 "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "fonts"
    ]
```

}

I then ran `react-native link`.

After that in my app I added in a rende:

```
 <Text style={{fontFamily:'ios-glyphs'}}>&#xf193;</Text>
```

On load of my app it is fine, but when i load the page that renders this custom font I get "Unrecognized font family 'ios-glyphs'", here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Mgz.png

The page does load after dismissing that error but the icon looks like a question mark in a box but my real icon is a star:

[image]

I then did some funky stuff. I thought I linked it wrong so I changed the folder path, and moved font to new folder and linked again. Then I went into xcode and saw two of them in "Resources" so I deleted the first one as that folder was no longer there.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Should I throw discard this commit? Will it make it like I never linked anything? I'm worried I might have screwed up my project with xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much to @sfratini - [React-Native can't resolve module for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842109/react-native-cant-resolve-module-for-fonts/42842941?noredirect=1#comment73770581_42842941) - the font name was actually totally different then file name, as hinted by the tutorial.

How I found the real font name was by following @sfratini's instructions.

I opened up xcode, and opened the `ios` folder in my project folder with xcode, like this.

I then added to AppDelegate.m this code:

```
  NSArray *families = [[UIFont familyNames] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
  NSMutableString *fonts = [NSMutableString string];
  for (int i = 0; i < [families count]; i++) {
    [fonts appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@:\n", families[i]]];
    NSArray *names = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:families[i]];
    for (int j = 0; j < [names count]; j++) {
      [fonts appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@\n", names[j]]];
    }
  }
  NSLog(@"%@", fonts);
```

Then found the new icon name in the console log.

My project folder:

[image]

Open with xcode:

[image]

[image]

Click on the folders, then add to AppDelegate.m the code then save and either run `react-native run-ios` or press "Play" button as in screenshot below (You need to recompile, I doubt hot reloading will work but I didn't test):

[image]

Then a full list of font names get spit out in the console log:

[image]

I did the fonts before linking, then after linking, and did a diff to find my font names.

[image]